# How do I determine how many kilobytes there are in a string of code using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, file, size

Let's say I have the following TypeScript code (represented as a string):

```
function greet(name: string): void {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}
```

How would I programmatically determine how many kilobytes there are in this string?

I'm currently using the following equation:

```
// NOTE: "string.length" represents the number of bytes in the string
const KB: number = (string.length / 1024).toFixed(2);
```

The problem is that the number often appears to be far too big or far too small to be correct.

When I put the string in an empty file and save it, my file manager's properties output a completely different size, sometimes it's off by 2-20 KB.

What am I doing wrong, should I be using `1000` bytes to represent a kilobyte instead of `1024`?

Comment: `string.length` is *half* the number of bytes in the string. Each character is two bytes.

Comment: And you'll have to post more code and an example of how it's not working. There's nothing mysterious about getting the length of a string or dividing a number by 1024.

Comment: This probably has little to do with TypeScript... seems like a runtime-only question.  In what encoding are you saving the string?  The [`length` of a string in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) represents how many UTF-16 code units the string takes up.  If you are saving the string in UTF-16, then the length is probably close to half the number of bytes of the file.  But you're more likely to be using UTF-8, which can be quite different.

Comment: @Pointy would it still be half the number of bytes if it was read from a file with a different encoding?

Comment: @jcalz I'm saving the string in a file with a `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: Once a string exists in JavaScript it's always UTF-16.  Mapping from file system character encoding to JavaScript happens when a file is read or written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A character in JavaScript string is encoded using `Unicode`, every engine has their own character set, the most popular one being `UTF-16`. Therefore, each character holds `2 bytes` of data. To find the total `kilobytes` being used by a string, find the number of `bytes` being used and divide it by `1024`

```js
const string = "abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc";

const b = string.length * 2;
const kb = (b / 1024).toFixed(2);

console.log(`${kb}KB`);
```

Comment: JavaScript is *always* UTF-16 internally, but local filesystems might be anything.

Comment: @Pointy as far as I've read the official ECMAScript standard, they don't specify any character set, they just want the languages following the standard to obey characters Unicode.

Comment: Section 11.8.4: *When generating these String values Unicode code points are UTF-16 encoded as defined in 10.1.1*

Comment: However it is true that JavaScript doesn't care that every two-byte element of a string is *valid* UTF-16.